# Uma chave estrangeira pode fazer parte de mais de uma tabela?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber se eu posso colocar uma chave estrangeira em mais de uma tabela, por exemplo, onde a entidade "competidores" na imagem é uma tabela e o atributo "id_competidor" é uma chave primária, e as demais entidades "competidores_documento", "competidores_endereco", "competidores_contato" e "competidores_colocacao" possuem como chave estrangeira o "id_competidor", seria possível fazer dessa forma? Se não qual melhor opção a se fazer?

Comment: Cada uma delas deverá ter uma FK (Foreign Key) relacionado ao competidor. Não há nada de errado nisso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lone Tomberry, não só pode, como deve. Chaves estrangeiras ou foreign key, como são comumente chamadas garantem a integridade dos dados de um banco. Atente-se ao tipo de relacionamento entre suas tabelas. Seguem dois artigos de referencia.

[SQL: Aprenda a utilizar a chave primária e a chave estrangeira](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-aprenda-a-utilizar-a-chave-primaria-e-a-chave-estrangeira/37636)

[Regras e Tipos de Relacionamentos](https://www.devmedia.com.br/exemplo-pratico-regras-e-tipos-de-relacionamentos-sql-server-2008-parte-3/18409)

Comment: A tabela também pode ter como atributo somente uma chave primaria ?

Comment: Sim. Mas uma chave primária pode ser formada por mais de uma coluna, dessa forma ela passa a ser uma **chave primária composta**. Leia um sobre o assunto nesse link: 

http://www.luis.blog.br/chave-primaria-simples-e-chave-primaria-composta.aspx